# how to use a flexible layout angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to create this page with the possibility to scroll on it if we need [image]

on each block, I'm going to add a specific component for the moment I m going to create these blocks each one with a specific color just to make the layout. i didn't get the same rslt as the picture
this is my html code :

```
<div class="sidebar">
  HELLO
</div>

<div class="container-red">
  <div>
    i'm the big block
  </div>
  <div class="block-blue">
    HI
  </div>
  <div class="block-black">
    HI AGAIN
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS :

```
.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  /* Additional styling for the sidebar */
}

.container-red {
  width: 80%;
  /* Additional styling for the container */
}

.block-blue {
  width: 50%;
  /* Additional styling for the blue block */
}

.block-black {
  width: 50%;
  /* Additional styling for the black block */
}
```

Comment: you can try https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be found useful, You may add the css property:

```
"overflow-y:scroll"
```

to the container you want to scroll.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

use `"overflow-y:scroll"` with box-specific height
also you can use https://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/